# Return statement does not work!

Tags: java, android

I have this simple method here:

```
private Node addItem(Node current, Node target) {
    if (current.data.getId() < target.data.getId()) {
        if (current.larger == null) {
            current.larger = target;
            Log.i("BinaryTree", "Added item: " + target.data.getId());
            return target;
        }
        return addItem(current.larger, target);
    } else {
        if (current.smaller == null) {
            current.smaller = target;
            Log.i("BinaryTree", "Added item: " + target.data.getId());
            return target;
        }
        return addItem(current.smaller, target);
    }
}
```

when i debug it, the code gets to the line 'return target;', and just skips it and goes to the last return statement - 'return addItem(current.smaller, target);'!
I have never in my life seen anything like this WTF?!?!

Comment: I should go out of the method if it reaches the return statement

Comment: oh wait wait, this is a recursive method <_<

Comment: Maybe you could look at the bytecode.  You get a double-return in the debugger only or also when the program runs on its own?

Comment: @End.Fouad I know but according to the stack trace, no recursion was made.

Comment: While "WTF" is technically is a question, you'll probably get a better answer if you frame your question properly...

Comment: Which 'return target' statement were you at?

Answer (score 8):

You probably saw your debug jump 'back' one method.

You're calling the addItem recursive; so the final return, where it actually will add it and return back up; will 'seem' to jump to another return, just because the Method call you're returning from originated there.

Comment: I watched the stack trace but no recursive call was shown other than the single call made from another method

Comment: In that case; can you at least post the entire stacktrace in your question from the breakpoint of the first return? (So before continuing to the 'last' return)

Comment: I think eclipse doesn't show the stack properly
I'm not seeing recursive calls in the debug window

Comment: The stack you see underneath the suspended thread in debug view should be the callstack at that point. Alternatively you can add System.out.println's before each return statement to see what is really called.

Answer (score 2):

If it's reaching that return statement then it should definitely be returning from that method. If you can't tell (since it's recursive) try placing a few `System.out.println()` statements.

For example:

```
...
Log.i("BinaryTree", "Added item: " + target.data.getId());
System.out.println("Returning: " + target.toString());
return target;
...
```